# Date dependent sequence numbers

Tags: c#, datetime

Which the right way to code date dependent sequence numbers using C#. Code below reflect my attempt to do this by my own.

What's required: Increasing `No` property during the year, and with the start of new year reset `numberSeed` to 0 and start increasing again for every `instance` of `Class`.

```
    private int _no;
        public int No
        {
            get { return _no; }
            set
            {
                var endOfYear = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 12, 31, 23, 59,59);
                var nowDate = DateTime.Now;
                int compareDates = DateTime.Compare(nowDate, endOfYear);
                if (compareDates != 0)
                {
                    _no = numberSeed;
                }
                else
                {
                    numberSeed = 0;
                }

                _no = numberSeed;
            }

        }
protected static int numberSeed = 1;

public Constructor()
        {
            No = numberSeed;
            numberSeed++;
        }
```

Comment: What made you share the code with us? Is there something wrong with it? Please describe the problem/question you would like answered. If there's nothing wrong with it and you would just like feedback, that's better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: That would theoretically only work if the App _never_ exited. Do you have a real-live usecase or is this only playing around? For a real-live usecase, I'd probably suggest utilizing a DB's sequence capability or at least something persistent. Otherwise you'll only ever be as good as your app crash / restart stats.

Comment: First of all, remove the last `_no = numberSeed;` in the `No` set method, it will always happed regardless of the result of the previous if statement.

Comment: So ... is your class called  `Constructor`?  And what if we do `No = 1337;`  what would you expect to happen?  See also [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)